# form replaced to textarea not give different output

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

I have two files

1. index.php
2. code.js

I have some code in index.php which contains forms and with the help of code.js. I am replacing pre tag with that form. So everything runs fine. For understand my problem you have to see my code.
So first of all I am giving my code

index.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.guru99.com/css/1140.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.guru99.com/css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/doc/docs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script src="http://code.guru99.com/php/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.guru99.com/Sanjay/lib/codemirror.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.guru99.com/perl/perl.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cperl.js"></script>
        <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
.CodeMirror {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    height: auto;
    width : 630px;
}
.CodeMirror-scroll {
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
</style>
<p>Integer : whole numbers e.g. -3, 0, 69. The maximum value of an integer is platform-dependent. On a 32 bit machine, its usually around 2 billion. 64 bit machines usually have larger values. The constant PHP_INT_MAX is used to determine the maximum value.</p>
<pre class="codeguru">say 'hi';</pre>
Let us now look at how PHP determines the data type depending on the attributes of the supplied data.
<pre class="codeguru">say 'hello';</pre>
Floating point numbers
<pre class="codeguru">say 'you r amazing';</pre>
Character strings
<pre class="codeNrun">say 'i am fine';</pre>

<form class="hidden code-box" method="GET" name="sample">
    <div dir="ltr">
        <textarea class="php" name="codeguru"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Run" />
    <br/>
    <br/>Output:
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="print-result4" disabled="true" cols="77"></textarea>
    <br/>
</form>
<form class="hidden code-box" method="GET" name="Nosample">
    <div dir="ltr">
        <textarea class="php" name="codeNrun"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

code.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var idIndex = 0;
    $('pre.codeguru').each(function () {
        var pre = this;
        var form = $('form[name=sample]').clone();
        $(form).removeAttr('name');
        $(form).removeClass('hidden');
        $($(form).find('textarea')[0]).val($(pre).text());
        var id = $(pre).attr('id');
        $(form).find('div textarea[name=code]').first().attr('id', id);
        $(form).find('#print-result4').first().attr('id', 'print-result' + idIndex++);
        $(pre).replaceWith(form);
    });

    var n = 0;
    $('input[type=button]').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function (x) {
            return function () {
                execute(x);
            };
        }(n++))
    });

    window.editors = [];
    $('textarea[name=codeguru]').each(function () {
        window.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this, {
            lineNumbers: true,
            matchBrackets: true,
            mode: "perl",
            tabMode: "shift"
        });
        editors.push(editor);
    });
     $('pre.codeNrun').each(function () {
        var pre = this;
        var form = $('form[name=Nosample]').clone();
        $(form).removeAttr('name');
        $(form).removeClass('hidden');
        $($(form).find('textarea')[0]).val($(pre).text());
        var id = $(pre).attr('id');
        $(form).find('div textarea[name=codeNrun]').first().attr('id', id);
        $(pre).replaceWith(form);
    });
    window.editors = [];
    $('textarea[name=codeNrun]').each(function () {
            window.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this, {
            lineNumbers: true,
            matchBrackets: true,
            mode: "perl",
            tabMode: "shift"
        });
        editors.push(editor);
    });
});

function execute(idx) {
    p5pkg.CORE.print = function (List__) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < List__.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById('print-result' + idx).value += p5str(List__[i])
        }
        return true;
    };

    p5pkg["main"]["v_^O"] = "browser";
    p5pkg["main"]["Hash_INC"]["Perlito5/strict.pm"] = "Perlito5/strict.pm";
    p5pkg["main"]["Hash_INC"]["Perlito5/warnings.pm"] = "Perlito5/warnings.pm";

    var source = editors[idx].getValue();

    var pos = 0;
    var ast;
    var match;
    document.getElementById('print-result' + idx).value = "";

    try {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        var js_source = p5pkg["Perlito5"].compile_p5_to_js([source]);
        var end = new Date().getTime();
        var time = end - start;
        // run
        start = new Date().getTime();
        eval(js_source);
        end = new Date().getTime();
        time = end - start;
    } catch (err) {
        //document.getElementById('log-result').value += "Error:\n";
    }
}
```

so now you can see that there are two forms names sample and Nosample like this

```
<form class="hidden code-box" method="GET" name="sample">
```

and

```
<form class="hidden code-box" method="GET" name="Nosample">
```

and there are two types of pre tags codeguru and codeNrun like this

```
<pre class="codeguru">say 'you r amazing';</pre>
```

And

```
<pre class="codeNrun">say 'i am fine';</pre>
```

So when I am replaced this pre code with form then when I am trying to run then the output is print in another textarea I cant understand why this can be happened.

Comment: You want to replace all `<pre>`s with `<form>`s? Why? They are completely and utterly different things.

Comment: @MrLister my guess would be to click a pre and then allow a person to edit the preformatted text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extra `window.editors = [];` in your code.

At first you create an `editors` array, then push it some CodeMirror objects, then you redefine `editors` to an empty array again... Just remove the second `window.editors = [];` line.

Secondly: what actually is the value of `id` variable here?

```
$(form).find('div textarea[name=code]').first().attr('id', id);
```

You're reading the `id` of the `textarea`, but looks like it's `undefined`, since there are no `id`s in the HTML.

A similar mistake in this line:

```
$(form).find('div textarea[name=codeNrun]').first().attr('id', id);
```

I guess `id` should be `'print-result3'` here, but it is `undefined` now.

Notice, that the additional digit to `id`'s bodies are added in the order `$('input[type=button]').each()` provides. This supposed to be the order the elements in the document have. Notice, that the original `button` is the last you can see on the screen.

---

I think there was a lack of explanation in my answer, how to target the button to an editor and corresponding `print-resultX`. I'll try to explain it here:

In the original `<input id="print-resultX" ... />` `X` should be a number of total `print-result` inputs i.e. a number of the CodeMirror objects, since when you're cloning the `form`, all clones are placed before this original form. During cloning corresponding `X`s are added to the body of the each `id` value.

This `X` value is passed to `execute(idx)` function as an argument `idx`, i.e. the clicked button "knows", which editor should be handled in the `execute()`, since `X` also represents an index in the `editors` array.

When adding `idx` to the body (= `'print-result'`) of the `id`, you can target actions to the specific print-result field.

Comment: @ Teemu CAN YOU TRY IT ON LIVE DEMO I AM GIVING YOU LINK

http://jsfiddle.net/Sanjayrathod/FH4EE/12/

Comment: Partial fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcRAd/1/). I'm not sure what is going on, there seem not to be `print-resultX`s at all, and only one editor : O.